# Establishing Serial Port communication through USB in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, serial-port

I am new to Ubuntu and I need to establish a serial port communication between my PC and microcontroller MSP430G2452.

On connection the USB available with the Launchpad and using `lsusb`.

It identifies the port as:

`Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0451:f432 Texas Instruments, Inc. eZ430 Development Tool`

After establishing such a connection what I need to do? My aim is to send a byte of information in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If linux understands that device and has a driver for it then you should find that a `/dev/ttyUSBn` device appears when you plug it in, which is a serial port that you can use.

If linux doesn't understand it already then you're going to have to write a driver for it, or find one that somebody else has written that you can use.

Comment: Thanks :) I was able to send 1 byte data using GtkTerm. But I need to send it indirectly using my GUI. Can you suggest what to do for that ??

Comment: @Prashant: Use standard Linux file open/write/close functions.